# How to generate multi workers and bind them to non-web Java applications on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, worker

I tried [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku.) to generate two workers on Heroku Server.

But based on this example I just have one worker run at the same time. Is it possible to generate 2 workers that run 2 difference jobs when the application starts?

I already tried to scale the workers by using:`heroku ps:scale worker=2`. But when I do this it only affects to WorkerProcess class and I have two WorkerProcess classes running at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have as many worker processes as you'd like. They just need to have different names in your Procfile. In the article you cited, the single worker is just called `worker`, but your Procfile could look something like this with two different workers called `updater` and `mailer`:

```
web: java -jar web-app.jar $PORT
updater: sh worker/target/bin/updater
mailer: sh worker/target/bin/mailer
```

If you're using the `appassembler-maven-plugin` shown in the article, you'll also need to add another `<program>...</program>` element for each of your workers so the nessisary start scripts are generated.