# "We are sorry, but something went wrong" on Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi guys I am quite new to the whole heroku deployment process. I have a simple rails app which works fine locally however once pushed to heroku it won't start.

I did some research and migrated my database on heroku server, still no luck. Couldm't find any other suggestions for this issue.

****My log file reads****

```
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310064+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523266+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3670
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310026+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:13] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310065+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310076+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523273+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310066+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310073+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523270+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310163+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:13] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310068+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523271+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310071+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310070+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310074+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523268+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-08-19T18:17:13.523261+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-19T18:17:13.310228+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:13] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-19T18:17:12.901672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 30258 -e production`
2014-08-19T18:17:18.000901+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-19T18:17:18.000922+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:18] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-19T18:17:18.001912+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 18:17:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=30258
2014-08-19T18:17:14.424153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-19T18:17:19.827157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=caa1fdcd-e68b-4273-be19-7ff784f1efcc fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=195ms status=304 bytes=978
2014-08-19T18:17:20.211571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4327c84979bcd01cb029e8d596d33bcf.css" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=1097
5509-080d-482e-9d4b-39f567a918ce fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=972
2014-08-19T18:17:20.286658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-021a93d581524a2def3d799b2f33250e.js" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc65
20f-d3de-46d6-86b6-20cf103a14a0 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=78ms status=200 bytes=956
2014-08-19T18:17:20.299452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_3-ec17f2302fd3697c2c737cb80f7b0cce.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=97b6
7e75-3a46-4935-8998-c2ee87af52ae fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=74ms status=200 bytes=974
2014-08-19T18:17:20.302530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_4-9d9c510ee90481ccd69d6e38eb7692a7.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=c83e
71e0-b569-40dd-ac5e-7d16effbcef7 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=78ms status=200 bytes=974
2014-08-19T18:17:20.299684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_2-a1246dc9b4df16e8e326ab14f868c6bf.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=e6d6
309b-6d24-4e81-8475-dd445fa7cb03 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=78ms status=200 bytes=974
2014-08-19T18:17:35.252443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=1e7a575f-c551-4405-880d-b27f18e910a1 fwd="54.237.200.138" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=404
2014-08-19T18:19:42.587164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about.html" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=98940865-c39b-4af5-a6bc-62e43fa6e63a fwd="173.228
.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=977
2014-08-19T18:21:55.926305+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H16 desc="herokuapp redirect" method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.heroku.com request_id=7e859339-5fd2-4210-b192-31f
eb9b77e7c fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno= connect= service= status=301 bytes=
2014-08-19T18:21:56.338185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=ce30bc43-fd75-43a5-9f7d-3cf1f81413d7 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=929
2014-08-19T19:17:41.684068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=b43fa96e-7727-4e53-be6c-2c08a3227b2f fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=955
2014-08-19T19:17:42.117729+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_1-391302847666d53202dab51e1ea4d8a8.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=bb43
9221-f9fa-4819-a1fd-878b3482a621 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1024
2014-08-19T19:17:42.107761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-4327c84979bcd01cb029e8d596d33bcf.css" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=a329
fe36-4be8-4c0a-a49a-f26d3eaaea67 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=1022
2014-08-19T19:17:42.107569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-021a93d581524a2def3d799b2f33250e.js" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=3c015
267-487b-405f-b6f5-050a9cfbd9f6 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1006
2014-08-19T19:17:42.124278+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_3-ec17f2302fd3697c2c737cb80f7b0cce.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=1064
1b06-fbe0-4ee9-bf4f-da73a57e2be3 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1024
2014-08-19T19:17:42.172274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/wolf_love_4-9d9c510ee90481ccd69d6e38eb7692a7.jpg" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=338a
628a-6287-4ca4-8a62-9612d4c1eeb9 fwd="173.228.119.84" dyno=web.1 connect=32ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=1025
2014-08-19T20:20:18.208955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-08-19T20:20:18.208413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435932+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 20:20:21] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435939+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435945+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435951+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435941+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435943+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435949+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463797+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:30258
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435958+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435971+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 20:20:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435948+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435946+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463803+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463801+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435961+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463790+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435955+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435953+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435959+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463799+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-08-19T20:20:21.435968+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-19 20:20:21] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-19T20:20:21.463804+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-08-19T20:20:20.887472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-08-19T20:20:22.651153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-22T01:50:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-22T01:50:18+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-08-22T01:54:37.238462+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:54:37.238369+00:00 heroku[api]: Set MANDRILL_USER_NAME config vars by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:55:28.435020+00:00 heroku[api]: Set MANDRILL_PASSWORD config vars by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:55:28.435141+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:56:46.567742+00:00 heroku[api]: Set EMAIL config vars by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:56:46.567798+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T01:56:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-22T01:57:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-08-22T01:59:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-22T01:59:40+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-08-22T02:28:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-22T02:29:28.747275+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 2104077 by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T02:29:28.747275+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T02:29:36.054272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-08-22T02:29:36.053949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-08-22T02:29:40.977848+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-22 02:29:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-22T02:29:40.978350+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-22 02:29:40] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=34280
2014-08-22T02:29:40.977871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-22 02:29:40] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-22T02:29:41.246409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-22T02:29:43.253996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=f4a5d0a1-38ac-4b90-bd48-7dc19200f61e fwd="54.166.81.223" dy
no=web.1 connect=2ms service=148ms status=500 bytes=406
2014-08-22T02:33:54.598503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=94cec33e-02e2-4d15-bbf9-7987e3a30b98 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=929
2014-08-22T02:34:24.917109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=abb89989-8437-4f94-a8c8-ac66e6a19549 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=3ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T02:44:16.334759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=bde316f7-0c17-45f6-8d31-aeb1a4bf8da8 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=878
2014-08-22T02:55:10.054373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=3db68bd5-5ba9-4dc2-8c48-4d149e1921c1 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T02:56:48.609525+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by tig_step@yahoo.com
2014-08-22T02:56:51.930749+00:00 heroku[run.3561]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-22T02:56:55.289664+00:00 heroku[run.3561]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-22T02:56:51.608107+00:00 heroku[run.3561]: Awaiting client
2014-08-22T02:56:51.640591+00:00 heroku[run.3561]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-08-22T02:56:55.275831+00:00 heroku[run.3561]: Process exited with status 0
2014-08-22T02:57:21.243045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=c20d8f62-a55b-48ac-9d51-2d0d41e58ce7 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T02:57:32.147058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=357b7298-1858-4c09-a436-01c058b2a1ab fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T02:57:45.750631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=10e67a67-5afe-42fa-ae1f-614feeba506e fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=878
2014-08-22T03:04:10.294837+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=31f4367b-2f93-44b9-8306-3b12b8415302 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T03:04:37.458850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=cfdc10a3-27a4-4868-a945-9a8ab66676db fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T03:05:01.152605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=e0bf4ca5-efb6-4761-930c-fd9fcfb7cc54 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=3ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=904
2014-08-22T03:05:56.837420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-earth-2791.herokuapp.com request_id=adc74f5a-ee61-42e4-97d2-817018d33c45 fwd="173.228.119.84" d
yno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=878
```

Any help i appreciated !!!

Comment: Do you have a Procfile, what is your memory footprint on local like, any weird dependencies, and have you tried using something besides Webrick, like Thin maybe, or Puma if your aiming for multi threaded safe code?

Comment: Also for now add config.log_level = :debug to your production.rb and see what the output looks like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku logs FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255667/heroku-logs-fatal-signalexception-sigterm)

Comment: @rovermicrover got it working. Thank you very much for pointing towards the right direction. I am new to stackoverflow as well so if there is a way to up-vote your answer let me know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this guide solves all the issues. I have it bookmarked for future deployments.

[getting-started-with-rails4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: Yeah tnx. I have actually followed that guide and @rovermicrover 's directions and succeeded, but the only thing to keep in mind is that Unicorn doesn't work on local host for Windows. Cheers.