# Heroku: We're sorry, but something went wrong( I have been looking for days)

Tags: android, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I know, so many people ask this same question, but none of the answers are working for me. Hopefully someone with more experience can help. I am using Devise in this application, if that helps.

When I run heroku ps:

```
=== web (Free): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
web.1: up 2015/11/25 02:39:53 (~ 26m ago)
```

Heroku Log:

```
2015-11-24T22:05:07.993413+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-24T22:05:07.993428+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-24T22:05:12.519003+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32783 -e production`
2015-11-24T22:05:17.529304+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:05:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-11-24T22:05:17.529328+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:05:17] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-11-24T22:05:17.529573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:05:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=32783
2015-11-24T22:05:17.734507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T22:08:42.923437+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=43d6d58c-398e-458f-b9d5-d8c573663ef1 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=76ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T22:08:43.081200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=3abfe83b-7381-4f1b-b901-b7e45ad7a56b fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-11-24T22:09:58.449471+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `db:migrate` by guildconcept@gmail.com
2015-11-24T22:10:00.441658+00:00 heroku[run.1339]: Awaiting client
2015-11-24T22:10:00.463935+00:00 heroku[run.1339]: Starting process with command `db:migrate`
2015-11-24T22:10:00.803616+00:00 heroku[run.1339]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T22:10:02.467681+00:00 heroku[run.1339]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-24T22:10:02.454690+00:00 heroku[run.1339]: Process exited with status 127
2015-11-24T22:10:11.644955+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by guildconcept@gmail.com
2015-11-24T22:10:13.866452+00:00 heroku[run.4044]: Awaiting client
2015-11-24T22:10:13.906184+00:00 heroku[run.4044]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-11-24T22:10:14.244007+00:00 heroku[run.4044]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T22:10:19.778358+00:00 heroku[run.4044]: Process exited with status 0
2015-11-24T22:10:19.767955+00:00 heroku[run.4044]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-24T22:11:04.093611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=6f5ee2ef-10e6-446d-97af-69749fd3c7a5 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T22:11:04.287865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=b503038f-9174-4cd2-904e-3391ced7fcb6 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-11-24T22:11:05.000050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=b24a20fd-63bd-4b95-b56e-6e22ee4a4e15 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T22:11:05.204728+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=c1340dca-2a8f-468a-a155-af24e994c09c fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-11-24T22:11:29.626953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=ecb2067b-26dc-40c8-b527-e1a2d8916df1 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T22:14:38.706423+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `db:migrate` by guildconcept@gmail.com
2015-11-24T22:14:41.036756+00:00 heroku[run.3858]: Starting process with command `db:migrate`
2015-11-24T22:14:41.003571+00:00 heroku[run.3858]: Awaiting client
2015-11-24T22:14:41.529782+00:00 heroku[run.3858]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T22:14:43.490006+00:00 heroku[run.3858]: Process exited with status 127
2015-11-24T22:14:54.658801+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by guildconcept@gmail.com
2015-11-24T22:14:56.424572+00:00 heroku[run.3306]: Awaiting client
2015-11-24T22:14:56.441974+00:00 heroku[run.3306]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-11-24T22:14:43.508096+00:00 heroku[run.3858]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-24T22:14:56.762584+00:00 heroku[run.3306]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T22:15:00.143588+00:00 heroku[run.3306]: Process exited with status 0
2015-11-24T22:15:00.103040+00:00 heroku[run.3306]: State changed from up to complete
2015-11-24T22:17:37.380714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=f1cd1525-7697-4bba-adec-bb5436af542f fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T22:17:37.579185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=9099fa00-7526-433b-8191-078b72a54c8b fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-11-24T22:51:40.649681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-11-24T22:51:40.650445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-11-24T22:51:46.152454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371522+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:51:47] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371527+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371531+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371533+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371532+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371534+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371532+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371538+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371664+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:51:47] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371534+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371536+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371606+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 22:51:47] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-11-24T22:51:47.412305+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371535+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.412309+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:32783
2015-11-24T22:51:47.412311+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371537+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.371538+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2015-11-24T22:51:47.412311+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-11-24T22:51:47.412312+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-24T22:51:48.125299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-11-24T23:09:53.602567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2015-11-24T23:09:53.602829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2015-11-24T23:09:55.419638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6079 -e production`
2015-11-24T23:09:59.250927+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:09:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-11-24T23:09:59.250946+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:09:59] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-11-24T23:09:59.259572+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:09:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=6079
2015-11-24T23:10:00.706946+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=6330fb41-d30c-48d1-86a3-b2fdfbfb983f fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-11-24T23:09:59.641116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-24T23:10:00.900587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-plains-8055.herokuapp.com request_id=fac0f43d-0385-445d-8325-29cc14c68ad1 fwd="74.70.151.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-11-24T23:43:31.043394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2015-11-24T23:43:31.043394+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2015-11-24T23:43:33.423424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039752+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:43:34] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039757+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039759+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039760+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039761+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039762+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039763+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039764+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039765+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039766+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039767+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039768+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039768+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039770+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039770+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039854+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:43:34] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-11-24T23:43:34.039919+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-24 23:43:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-11-24T23:43:34.070390+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-11-24T23:43:34.070396+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-11-24T23:43:34.070395+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:6079
2015-11-24T23:43:34.070397+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-11-24T23:43:34.070398+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-24T23:43:34.912741+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior when you are on the free dyno option and using Webbrick for your webserver. When the dyno is put to sleep or any other modifying action (restart, scale down etc), webbrick gets a sigterm and is shut off.
Take a look at the Heroku help articles on this topic as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255667/heroku-logs-fatal-signalexception-sigterm) that may be similar.

[heroku - dyno sleeping](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping)

[heroku - default web server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server)