# Why did my Herokuapp idle and shut down while in use?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Why did my free-tier (but credit-card confirmed) Heroku app idle and shut down unexpectedly while being used?  I was watching it log my activity on an active connection to the app when it suddenly idled and shut down.

```
heroku[web.1]: Idling
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?...
heroku[web.1]: Unidling
heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: > start /app<some other stuff>
app[web.1]: > node index.js $PORT
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: Server running on port 45155.
2heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Heroku server status 143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767685/understanding-heroku-server-status-143)

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Heroku

If an app has a free web dyno, and that dyno receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period, it will sleep.

If your account has free dyno hours left then it will become active as soon as web traffic is received.

Personal accounts are given a base of 550 free dyno hours each month. In addition to these base hours, accounts that verify with a credit card will receive an additional 450 hours added to the monthly free dyno quota. This means you can receive a total of 1000 free dyno hours per month if you verify your account with a credit card.

Make sure you haven't utilized your free 1000 Hours!! which is pretty evident is not the case since your app restarted!!
The traffic might be the issue!

Comment: My app was receiving traffic while it shut down.  It's an online game and I was literally playing it, and watching the logs as they logged my activity, when it shut down.

Comment: Is it normal that it would reset my sql data base?

Comment: @ConstantineWesterink Yes, if it's sqlite as heroku has what's called an ephemeral file system. So new files added during runtime do not persist.